# How do I monitor webrole instances in Azure

Tags: azure

I have a WebRole with two identical instances Instance 1 and Instance 2.
When a user hits the url of my application, how can I find which instance served the request?
I am not able to find this in Azure portal.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember this right, WAD also has the instance ID:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines/

Visual Studio → Configure Diagnostics → Log Directories:

[image: Visual-Studio-Configure-Diagnostics]